# For loop doesn't run

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have an app where users can browse an image gallery (array of images fetched via API) and "Favourite" images which creates a separate array and displays them further down the page in it's own section. It works fine but allows duplicates.

I've created a for loop that loops through the favourites array and compares the current active slide to the contents of the array with the idea that it will display an error message if someone tried to add an image twice. Unfortunately, it doesn't work but also doesn't throw an error.

However if I push the item to the array outside of the for loop (line 3 here currently commented out) it works as expected (i.e logs duplicate). I can't figure out why the for loop won't run...

```
faveBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let faveHtml = ''
        //faveArray.push(imagesArray[activeSlide])
    for (let i = 0; i < faveArray.length; i++) {
        if (imagesArray[activeSlide] === faveArray[i]) {
            console.log('Duplicate')
        } else {
            console.log('Not duplicate')
            faveArray.push(imagesArray[activeSlide])
        }
        faveHtml += `< img class = "fave-img"
src = "${faveArray[i]}" > `
    }
    faveImages.innerHTML = faveHtml
})
```

Comment: Please include all relevant code, including html (a minimal reproducible example) and variables such as `imagesArray` and `faveArray`.

Comment: It's probably your variable `faveArray.` If it doesn't exist, it doesn't have a "length." I'd bet this is a scoping problem, but you'll need to provide more details to get better advice.

Comment: looks like you have to loop `imagesArray` as `faveArray` will be empty initially and it will having length as 0.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the guidance everyone. It was as pointed out here the "length" of an empty array. I added some placeholder data, adjusted my code a bit to include a second loop and it now works how I wanted it:

````
    let faveHtml = ''
    let dupeFound = false
    for (let i = 0; i < faveArray.length; i++) {
        if (imagesArray[activeSlide] === faveArray[i]) {
            dupeFound = true
            for (let j = 0; j < faveArray.length; j++) {
                faveHtml += `<img class="fave-img" src="${faveArray[j]}">`
            }
        }
    }
    if (!dupeFound) {
        faveArray.shift()
        faveArray.push(imagesArray[activeSlide])
        for (let j = 0; j < faveArray.length; j++) {
            faveHtml += `<img class="fave-img" src="${faveArray[j]}">`
        }
    }
    faveImages.innerHTML = faveHtml
})```

Now I just need to re-factor it a bit.
````